# C# Principal System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement EmailAddress

Tags: c#

I feel like I'm losing my mind here. I'm querying AD with a person's first and last name in order to get their AD ID and email address. At design time there is no EmailAddress property but at run-time it exists. What gives and how can I access this EmailAddress at run-time if it won't compile if I code it at design time?

```
private Dictionary<string, string> GetActiveDirectoryID(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

            // query AD by first and last name
            UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
            qbeUser.GivenName = firstName;
            qbeUser.Surname = lastName;

            PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

            var found = srch.FindOne();

            result.Add("id", found.SamAccountName);
            result.Add("email", found.EmailAddress);    //??

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: `FindOne` returns a [`Principal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal(v=vs.110).aspx).  That class does not have an email address property.  You need to cast it to a type that does.  What is the runtime type of `found`?

Comment: I see that if I use dynamic found = srch.FindOne() it works, but not sure if it'll blow up at some point.

Comment: You need to cast it to the proper type that inherits from `Principal`.  Like I noted in my first comment.  Again, what is the runtime type of `found`?

Comment: It's a UserPrincipal so all good now thanks.